# Live Data Migration From Tokumx 2.0 To Percona Server For MongoDB 3.0 With Zero or Minimum Downtime ( PSMDB )

Tags: database, live, data-migration, percona, tokumx

Live Data Migration From Tokumx 2.0 To PSMDB (Percona Server For MongoDB 3.0)

=======

I am doing live data migration from Tokumx 2.0 replicaset cluster to Percona server for mongodb 3.0 using the following Guide specified Link Below :
Visit https://github.com/dbpercona/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration/blob/master/ZeroDowntimeMigration.md#catchup

This document describes how to migrate from a source TokuMX 2.x server to a target Percona Server for MongoDB 3.x (PSMDB) with zero to minimal downtime. The migration process requires the following phases:

Snapshot - Point in time source Backup
Dump - Convert source backup to BSON
Restore - Load BSON into target
Catchup - Play operation log from source to target
Switch - Reconfigure application layer to use target

During the catchup phase command for oplog sync.
./bin/toku2mongo --from localhost:27017 --gtid 4:35 --host mongoprodcluster1a:37017 2>&1 | tee ./toku2mongo.out &

Gives error :

> connected to: mongoprodcluster1a:37017 Sat Jul 16 11:57:31.655
>   [toku2mongo] ERROR: error replaying command op { op: "c", ns:
>   "cases.$cmd", o: { beginLoad: 1, ns: "cases", indexes: {}, options: {}
>   } }: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no such command: beginLoad", code: 59, bad
>   cmd: { beginLoad: 1, ns: "cases", indexes: {}, options: {} } } Sat Jul
>   16 11:57:31.655 [toku2mongo] Exiting while processing GTID 4:35 Sat
>   Jul 16 11:57:31.655 [toku2mongo] Use --gtid=4:35 to resume. Sat Jul 16
>   11:57:31.655 [toku2mongo] Saved GTID to file
>   /mnt/tokumx-bkup/toku2mongo-2.0.2-el6-x86_64/**toku2mongo_saved_timestamp**.
>   Sat Jul 16 11:57:31.655 [toku2mongo] I'll automatically use this value
>   next time if you run from this directory and don't pass --gtid.

Any help Appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the execution of a custom command on the TokuMX 2.x side that is not supported in Percona Server for MongoDB (3.x).  The command is being executed by your application during the catchup phase.  This is causing the error you are seeing.

The command being executed in the application is the `db.runCommand({ 'beginLoad' : [ 'coll1' , ... ] })` command which is documented [here](https://github.com/Tokutek/mongo/wiki/TokuMX-Bulk-Loading)

Before beginning the migration process.  It is important to ensure that the application does not implement any custom TokuMX 2.x features that are not supported by Percona Server for MongoDB (3.x).  This includes the transaction commands as well as the bulk loading commands.

The best way to ensure this is to do a full coverage test of the applications functionality with Percona Server for MongoDB in a draft environment before beginning the migration process.

Comment: I have checked in Tokumx 2.x, and i found the BeginLoad and Transactions command in it. Whereas , i have not found  BeginLoad and Transaction  commands in Percona server for mongodb 3.x. Now if this is the case what are the recommendations? Do we need to re-configure the TokuMX or add something in Percona server for mongodb 3.x or need to update the toku2mongo script? Or migration is not possible?

Comment: Hi gahmed, the application will need to be modified to remove the bulk loading and transactions. Percona Server for MongoDB follows the upstream MongoDB 3.x source code which uses optimistic concurrency and cannot support complex transactions. TokuMX was a low-level re-write of the MongoDB 2.x storage logic that does support transactions. However, there has not been enough commercial interest in TokuMX to continue development.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed reply.I still have a couple of questions in my mind. Is it a simple process to modify TokuMX  to remove bulk loading and transactions? Do we need a downtime for modification?

Comment: The real question is: Does the application require complex, multi-document/multi-collection/multi-operation atomicity?   Please contact Percona for advice and assistance.